# Improve exim regex to catch everything but specified adresses

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm using this regex to catch any incoming e-mails excluding mails from from specific people.

```
^(.(?!(zulgrib@exemple.com|zulgrib@example.org)).)*$/i
```

This regex correctly let through these scenarios

```
Zulgrib at example.com <Zulgrib@example.com>
<Zulgrib@example.com>
<Zulgrib@example.com> In behalf of Robot
```

Regex correctly catches these kind of headers

```
Associate@example.org
Your Associate Associate@example.com
```

If an excluded e-mail address is alone, it will catch it, I would like to prevent that. Example:

```
zulgrib@exemple.org
```

What should be modified to allow this to work and why my current method is not correct ?
If I understand the documentation, `.` matches any character, void is not a character, but using `*` is not working.

Comment: Do you want to match all except the last example? See [`^(?:(?!zulgrib@exemple\.com|zulgrib@example\.org).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ww9LDg/1). Or do you mean you need to only avoid matching the input if it is equal to the `zul...@example.org`? See [`^(?!zulgrib@exemple\.com$|zulgrib@example\.org$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ww9LDg/2)?

Answer (score 1):

First, some issues in your current regex:

- `exemple` has a different spelling than `example`
- Literal points need to be escaped. So `\.com` instead of `.com`.
- There are two dots (`.`) in the outermost group, which means you only capture text with an even number of characters, and don't exclude the case where the email addresses start at the beginning of the string. The first dot should not be there.

To make an exception for when the email address is the only thing in the input, I fear you'll have to specify that as a separate alternative in which (unfortunately) you'll have to repeat those email addresses:

[`^(?:zulgrib@example\.com|zulgrib@example\.org)$|^(?!(?:.*(?:zulgrib@example\.com|zulgrib@example\.org))).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/uewOGy/1)